# Is Disk Utility very accurate in S.M.A.R.T. status?

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, bash, high-sierra

So I have a simple bash script which checks whether my S.M.A.R.T. status is Verified if not it throws me a pop up alert. But is Disk utility very accurate when a drive is failing or not. Like suppose if my  OEM SSD is failing one day will it show me the S.M.A.R.T. status as "Failing"? I have high Sierra on my Mac.[image]
EXAMPLE

Comment: Disk Util's "Verifed" or "Failing" is the hard disk equivalent of the Check Engine Light (aka idiot light) on your car.  If it's on, something is definitely wrong but you don't know what specifically.    If you need something more granular than Disk Utility look at [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) or [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/)

Comment: @Allan thanks for the reply I have decided to use smartReporter and smartmontools